# Navigate HTML Source while performing WatiN tests

Tags: c#, watin

I am performing actions on the page during WatiN tests. What is the neatest method for asserting certain elements are where they should be by evaluating the HTML source? I am scraping the source but looking for a clean way to navigate the tags pulled back.

UPDATE: Right now I am thinking about grabbing certain elements within HTML source using regular expressions and then analysing that to see if other elements exist within. Other thoughts appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IE.ContainsText("myText") is not enough for your scenario?

Answer (score 0):

I would use [XPath](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/) to navigate tags in HTML without using regexps.